# Who are the sibling groups in this picture?

Tags: code-geass, monogatari-series, durarara, mawaru-penguindrum, wagnaria

The picture:

[image: anime siblings]

It looks like fanart, but I'm pretty sure the characters are all from something and not original characters, since I recognize Lelouch and Nunnally Lamperouge on the far left, and the Araragi siblings Karen-chan, Koyomi, and Tsukihi-chan at the center. Who are the other characters? Answers identifying any or all are appreciated.

Comment: [e-shuushuu](http://e-shuushuu.net/image/?image_id=482744) seems to list all of them. You could probably figure out who is who based on that, but there are 14 and I don't recognize all of them so I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: @LoganM Yeah, I used your iqdb tip from [this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13871/7579) to find them all, so I wrote out my own answer. Wish I could upvote that post twice.

Comment: As part of our [cleanup of image-only id requests](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/image-only-id-request-cleanup?cb=1), I'm voting to close this question by some guy I don't know that inexplicably garnered 6 upvotes and another 12 for its answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I answered my own question partway through writing it with a visit to http://iqdb.com. Rather than delete the question, I made it a shill for iqdb (brought to my attention by Logan M. in [this question's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13867/who-is-this-girl-with-red-hair-in-a-sheep-outfit).) iqdb led me to [this page](https://chan.sankakucomplex.com/post/show/1249239) that lists all the series and characters in this picture.

The far left pair is Lelouch and Nunnally Lamperouge from Code Geass.

Next to Lelouch and Nunnally are Izaya Orihara and his younger twin sisters Mairu and Kururi, from [Durarara!!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Durarara!!_characters).

Next are Hiromi Souma and Aoi Yamada from Working!!. They're not actually siblings, but Aoi tries to make Hiromi into her big brother.

Then we have the Araragi siblings from the Monogatari series. (The reason I found this picture.)

Next to them are Shouma and Himari Takakura from [Mawaru Penguindrum](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10721/Mawaru_Penguindrum).

The pair on the far right is twin brothers Yuuta and Yuuki Asaba from [Kimi to Boku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimi_to_Boku_%28manga%29).

Comment: ah! thanks for reminding me, durarara is getting a second season btw.. YAY

Comment: @ton.yeung I keep meaning to check out the first season. Even though I liked Baccano, Durarara always slips my mind when it's time for a new show.